# push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification

please guide me how to implement the push notification in android. according to my application when server hits any information at any time i want to display that info at that time. what i need to implement this in my android plateform.

Comment: Please go through this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606101/how-to-implement-the-push-notification-in-android/66075534#66075534

Comment: Please find the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606101/how-to-implement-the-push-notification-in-android/66075534#66075534

Answer (score 0):

With Android 2.2 it is possible using the [Cloud to Device Messaging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html).

Comment: is it possible to enable push notification in 1.6

Comment: There are other ways but C2DM is not available before 2.2

Comment: Ok and thanks for your advice. Will you tell me how can i implement it in 1.5

Answer (score 0):

As Alopix mentionned, the automatic way to do that is through Android Cloud, since Android 2.2.
Now If you want it before 2.2, here is what I choose to do to enable it in my application :
First, put a switch in your application, testing for the version of the Android system of the phone you are running on (with [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) and then the field SDK_INT).this way you know if you are in equal or above 2.2 or below.
Then, if you are below, you need to create a small php page, with for instance a timer, that will be executed regularly by your server, and you do a simple http request on this page to check if there are news available for your application.
Does that help?